# Sequelize WHERE AND syntax with functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

i'm using Sequelize 5.18.0 and sequelize-typscript. I need to do a where clause with `and` and a `.fn` to find rows where a DateTime column are from a given day.
What is the correct syntax to do this?

```
  return STTermin.schema(ctx.tenant).findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          [Op.and]: {
            Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.col('von')), '2019-10-17'),
            bis: {
              [Op.is]: null
            }
          }
        },
```

Which gives me the following error:

[image]

Comment: Please, put your code and error as text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `Op.and` and `Op.or` require an array of arguments. So:

```
 [Op.or] : [
    [Op.and]: [
       Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('DATE', Sequelize.col('von')), '2019-10-17'),
       {bis: {[Op.is]: null}}
    ],
    { otherColumn : 123455 }  /* some other condition */
]
```

FWIW, I find the [Operator Aliases](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/querying.html#operators-aliases) to improve code clarity...

Comment: it works, big THX. However i wonder if Op.or requires an array, because the second part of the query (the second part of the OR) looks like this: [Op.and]: { von: {[Op.lte]: dayString}, bis: {[Op.gte]: dayString} } which to me look like an Object

Comment: I'm surprised that an Object works (but testing confirms).  I also did find a potential problem using an object rather than an array: for example `[Op.and]: { von: {[Op.lt]: '2019-10-01'}, von: {[Op.gt]: '2019-10-02'}} }` produces only `von > '2019-10-02'` ... where you might expect `von < '2019-01-01' AND von > '2019-10-02'`